How to Restart SIM Card based Cellular Internet Service in Windows
I am having a problem with my cellular internet service (via a SIM card9 on a Windows 11 system. From time to time it will not reconnect to the network. Turning it off and on again via the network & internet settings or the notification area on the taskbar doesn't help.
In my first searches, I only found the usual options to reset the network stack etc. so the only working solution I currently have is to restart Windows. Is there a way to just restart the cellular service to at least get it temporarily working again?
